# Изменить страницу "Веб-страница недоступна" при отсутствии интернет

Tags: android, webview

Добрый день.
В андроиде я новичок. Возник вопрос:
Есть собственно `webview` которое откроет некий сайт. 
Если отключить интернет то появляется окно  "Веб страница недоступна" и т.д.

Есть ли возможность изменить именно эту страницу?

Comment: Самый умный совет Проверить есть ли доступ к интернету

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы можете отловить ошибку, перекрыв у webView `onReceivedError`, после чего подменить `html`-ky или закрыть `webview`

```
 webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
            //logic
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете добавить проверку на наличие интернет-подключения и при отсутствии оного, кормить в `WebView` необходимую информацию. К примеру:

```
if (isConnected()) {
    //Стандартная Ваша загрузка
} else {
    // Показываем текст:
    webView.loadData("Извините, интернета нет, вот мое сообщение/пожелание", "text/html", "utf-8");
    //Либо кормим подготовленную страницу:
    //webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/myPage.html");
}
```